# Yii2 without email confirmation user can't login

Tags: email, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

When user sign up, system send a confirmation email to user its work good but without any email confirmation system automatic login or user can login. How can i solve this, that user should confirm email before login and if user not confirmed an email user can't be login?

i am using [this project: 
Yii 2 Advanced Template With Rbac User Managment](https://github.com/DezMonT765/yii2-advanced-template-rbac)

my LoginForm model code

```
namespace common\models;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * Login form
 */

class LoginForm extends Model
{
public $email;
public $password;
public $rememberMe = true;

protected  $_user = false;


/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // username and password are both required
        ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        [['email','password'], 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        // rememberMe must be a boolean value
        ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
        // password is validated by validatePassword()
        ['password', 'validatePassword','skipOnEmpty'=>false],
    ];
}

/**
 * Validates the password.
 * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
 *
 * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
 * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
 */
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->$attribute)) {
            $this->addError('email', Yii::t('messages','Incorrect password or email.'));
            $this->addError('password', Yii::t('messages','Incorrect password or email.'));
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
 *
 * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
 */
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Finds user by [[username]]
 *
 * @return User|null
 */
public function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
        $this->_user = User::findByEmail($this->email);
    }

    return $this->_user;
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'email' => Yii::t('app','Email'),
        'password' => Yii::t('app','Password')
    ];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find below function in common/models/User.php

```
 public static function findByEmail($email)
    {
        return static::findOne(['email'=>$email,'status'=>self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }
```

and replace it with following

```
public static function findByEmail($email)
{
    return static::findOne(['email'=>$email,'status'=>self::STATUS_ACTIVE,'email_verification_status'=>self::EMAIL_VERIFIED]);
}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 5):

it happen because the email status inactive by default, to change this status you can go to

> common/models/user.php

and change the **rule function** from

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_INACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_INACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }
```

to

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_INACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Changing status on the backend (user table) to 10 worked like charm

Comment: UPDATE `user` SET `status` = '10' WHERE `user`.`id` = [put your user ID];

Answer (score 0):

**You need to set up SMTP for email verification but for localhost you can use the following steps.**

- There is a file name like *2021XXXX-162725-6907-8769.eml* in the
  directory of ‘@frontend/runtime/mail’.
- Open it and click on the link in it, and then you got a message ‘Your
  an email has been confirmed!’ in your web browser.
- Now, your email is verified and you can proceed to login user.

Answer (score -1):

Use sataus = 10 in user table in database it works for me.